# How to add unknown heights surfaces in a FlexScrollView?

Tags: scrollview, famo.us

I'm using a FlexScrollView from famous-flex to implement a chat. The different bubbles containing the messages have an unknown height and depend on the message content. Here is the way I add the surfaces :

```js
var scrollView = new FlexScrollView({
    flow: true,
    insertSpec: {
        opacity: 0
    },
    nodeSpring: {
        dampingRatio: 0.8,
        period: 500
    },
    autoPipeEvents: true
});

var _surf = new Surface({
    size: [undefined, true],
    content: someHTMLTemplate
});
scrollView.push(_surf);
```

I thought using size: [undefined, true] would work as I saw here: https://github.com/aknip/famous-angular-with-famous-flex and here: 
https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex-chat

I also managed to do it using the classic scrollView from famous but I'd really want to use the FlexScrollView.

Comment: Your example should work. What does your HTML-template look like? Can you share an online example so I can debug it?

Comment: I actually solved it. You are right, something were wrong with my html template. I used different elements with absolute position inside a div container which height was not the good one (0 in fact). I removed the position: absolute from my elements and set float: something instead. Thank you very much for your fast reply!

Comment: Glad you found the problem!